# Gradle: How to derive project directory path in a Gradle plugin?

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

Gradle v2.9 (Old, we're upgrading soon)

I'm trying to create a Gradle plugin by following [Writing Gradle Plugins](https://guides.gradle.org/writing-gradle-plugins/). How can I have the plugin "derive" the project's top directory, that is where `build.gradle` file is? if the plugin creates an `hello` task, I want it to do this

```
$ pwd
/some_path/project1
$ ls
build.gradle gradlew gradle gradle.properties src
$ ./gradlew hello
Hello /some_path/project1
```

Comment: [`Project#getRootDir()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getRootDir--). There are other getters, such as `#getProjectDir()`, `#getBuildDir()`, and `#getRootProject()`. You may also want to check out methods such as [`#file(Object)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#file-java.lang.Object-). However, I'm not sure how many are available in Gradle 2.9 (links are for 6.0 documentation).

Comment: [Here's the documentation for 2.9](https://docs.gradle.org/2.9/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html). Looks like the methods I mentioned are present.

Comment: You can use `project.file('.').getAbsolutePath()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the members' comments, I'm able to do this

Per the comments, I did this in the code

```
package org.example.greeting;

import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project;

public class GreetingPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getTasks().create("hello", Greeting.class, (task) -> {
            task.setMessage("Hello");
            task.setRecipient("World");
            // Added this line per comments from members
            task.setProjectDir(project);
        });
    }
}
```

...and...

package org.example.greeting;

```
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction;
import org.gradle.api.Project;
import java.io.*;

public class Greeting extends DefaultTask {
    private String message;
    private String recipient;
    private File projectDir;
    private Project project;

    public String getMessage() { return message; }
    public void setMessage(String message) { this.message = message; }

    public String getRecipient() { return recipient; }
    public void setRecipient(String recipient) { this.recipient = recipient; }

    public File getProjectDir() { return projectDir; }
    public void setProjectDir(File projectDir) { this.projectDir = projectDir; }

    public Project getProject() { return project; }
    public void setProject(Project project) { this.project = project; }

    @TaskAction
    void sayGreeting() {
        System.out.printf("%s, %s, %s!\n", getProject().getRootDir().toString(), getMessage(), getRecipient()); 
    }       
}
```

and it works now.